# how to initialize char array using pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, char

Could some one share why below program crashes?

```
void main() {

    char *arr = "abcd";
    arr[3] = 'f';
}
```

Comment: Because it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between `char *` and `char []`! So this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char arr[] = "abcd";
    arr[3] = 'f';

    return 0;
}
```

For further information see:

[What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/3933332)